# Where can I use 'beadm'?

Tags: solaris, grub, gnu

I want to use `beadm destroy` but I don't know where can I type that command... Do I have to type it here or where?

[image]

Comment: That picture shows the grub boot loader prompt, before you boot into Solaris.  You need to boot Solaris before you can run Solaris commands like `beadm`.

Answer (score 1):

`beadm` can be found when Solaris 11 is booted. So first boot the (Solaris) operating system, login as user and then execute `beadm`. Some features are probably prohibited (like destroy) and only available as privileged user.